# What's the Opcode in LLVM ICmpInst represents for?

Tags: llvm

I have gotten the opcode of an ICmpInst by following codes,

```
unsigned op = icmp->getOpcode();
```

and now I want to do different operation according to the opcode,so I written following codes,

```
switch (op){
    case 32:
        exp = (opl == opr);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

and it comes to problem, I just know that opcode '32' represents 'eq',but what about others ?
Where can I find other opcode represents for or Is there have a more efficient way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opcode of an `icmp` instruction is simply `Instruction::ICmp`, but that doesn't tell you anything about what kind of comparison is performed. All it tells you is that you're dealing with an `icmp` instruction, which you already knew.

What you want is `getPredicate`, which returns a value of the [`Predicate` enum](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CmpInst.html#a283f9a5d4d843d20c40bb4d3e364bb05), which defines constants like `CmpInst::ICMP_EQ` that you can use inside your switch statement.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks ! It really helps.